# How to kubectl exec to freshly created pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

We use `kubectl set image` to rollout a new version `2.0.0` of an existing application. We then use `kubectl rollout status` to wait for the new pod to become ready so that we can run some basic tests.

The problem is, `kubectl rollout status` returns (implying the new v2 pod is ready) but when we use `kubectl exec` we ALWAYS land in the old v1 pod.

```bash
$ date
Mon 13 Feb 2023 02:33:50 PM CET
$ k set image deploy/myapp myapp=myapp:2.0.0 && k rollout status deploy/myapp
deployment.apps/myapp image updated
Waiting for deployment "myapp" rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
Waiting for deployment "myapp" rollout to finish: 1 old replicas are pending termination...
deployment "myapp" successfully rolled out
```

Here, we assume the new version is running. Let's check:

```bash
$ k exec deploy/myapp -- show_version
1.0.0
```

Nope, it's still the old version.
Check the deplyoment:

```bash
$ k get deploy/myapp
NAME       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
myapp   1/1     1            1           273d
```

Looks ready (K9S shows 1 pod "Terminating" and 1 pod ready).
Check again:

```bash
$date
Mon 13 Feb 2023 02:34:00 PM CET
$ k exec deploy/myapp -- show_version
1.0.0
```

Nope, check the pods:

```bash
kubectl get pod | grep myapp-
myapp-79454d746f-zw5kg         1/1     Running       0              31s
myapp-6c484f86d4-2zsk5         1/1     Terminating   0              3m5s
```

So our pod is running, we just can't exec into it - it always "picks" the terminating pod:

```bash
$date
Mon 13 Feb 2023 02:34:10 PM CET
$ k exec deploy/myapp -- show_version
1.0.0
```

Wait 20-30s:

```bash
$ date
Mon 13 Feb 2023 02:34:25 PM CET
$ k exec deploy/myapp -- show_version
2.0.0
```

Finally we have `exec` on the correct pod.

Why/how can we wait for the old pod to terminate?
OR
How can we ensure we exec into the correct pod for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

> Even better would be to get the new_pod id and exec directly into that.

Also possible, yes. Try this:

```
k rollout status deploy/myapp >/dev/null && \
  k get po -l app=myapp | grep Running | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I{}  kubectl exec {} -- show_version
```

> I would love to know what controls that 30s time.

This can be configured using the [terminationGracePeriodSeconds](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace) field in the pod's spec. The value defaults to, you guessed it right, 30s. If you're not concerned about data loss (due to the immediate shutdown), it can be set to 0. After that you can directly exec into the new pod:

```yaml
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
```

```
k rollout status deploy/myapp >/dev/null && k exec deploy/myapp -- show_version
```

---

While being "Terminated" the old pod is still in [phase *Running*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase), and the `kubectl exec deploy/myapp` seems to use the [first *Running* pod of the deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec) .

I would suggest:

1. Retrieve and store the name of the currently running pod in a temp variable prior to deployment (assuming the pod has the label `app=myapp`)

```
$ old_pod=$(kubectl get pods -l app=myapp -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')
```

2. Deploy

```
$ k apply -f Deployment.yaml
```

3. Wait [until the rollout is done](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-status-em-)

```
$ k rollout status deploy/myapp
```

4. Wait [until the `old_pod` is deleted](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait)

```
$ k wait --for=delete pod/$old_pod --timeout -1s
```

5. Check the new pod

```
$ k exec deploy/myapp -- show_version
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting approach. Even better would be to get the new_pod id and exec directly into that. My feeling is kubernetes keeps the old pods for about 30s. I would love to know what controls that 30s time. Creating a liveness probe for the pod did not help reduce this time.

Comment: @Marc updated my answer regarding your remarks.

Answer (score 1):

you can exec inside a pod by using this command :-

$ kubectl exec -it {pod-id} -n {namespace} -- bash

In your case, use the running pod Id :-

$kubectl exec -it myapp-79454d746f-zw5kg -- bash

No need of using deployment name to exec inside a pod , since deployment will be representing both the pods .

Comment: We don't know the pod name/id as we are deploying a new version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
Kubectl exec -it pod-name -c main /bin/bash
```

Use this command to go into the pod. To list the pods use the below commands

```
kubectl get pods -l app=myapp
Kubectl get pods
```

Sometimes it takes few seconds for the pod to come up.

Comment: We don't know the pod name/id as we are deploying a new version.